# Spring @Configuration runtime injection

Tags: java, spring

In my **non-Boot** Spring 5 project I need to manually register and initialize some beans. **After that** I want to add a `@Configuration` class to context, that imports a config from an external lib:

```
@Configuration
@Import(ExtLibConfig.class)
public class MyExtLibConfig {

  @Bean
  public ExtLibBean extLibBean() {
   return ExtLibBean.builder().build();
  }

}
```

`ExtLibConfig` has many of its own `@ComponentScan` and `@Import`, and I wish them all to be configured automatically, including my `ExtLibBean`.

Is it possible to do so in runtime? External lib scans `ApplicationContext`, and I need it to do so, **when my manually registered beans are added**.

**UPD**:
The problem is not actual about beans register order. The ext lib is scanning `ApplicationContext` after its refresh, so I need my beans to be there at this time

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by specifying "after that". What is the intended purpose of trying to sequence bean initialization like that?

Comment: @chrylis I am trying to add mocks to `ApplicationContext`, so the ext lib could scan them as beans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to implement `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor`

```
public class MyMockBeanDefinitioRegistrynPostProcessor implements BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) throws BeansException {
        // registry.registerBeanDefinition(mockBeanClass, mockBeanDefinition);...

    }

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        // nothing to do
    }
```

Then declare it as a `Bean`:

```
@Configuration
public class MockBeanConfig {

    @Bean
    public MyMockBeanDefinitioRegistrynPostProcessor mockBeanDefinitionPp() {
        return new MyMockBeanDefinitioRegistrynPostProcessor();
    }

}
```

And add it to context:

```
AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();

context.register(MockBeanConfig.class);
context.register(MyExtLibConfig.class);

context.refresh();
```